# Flutter: flutter_html_audio does not work

Tags: html, flutter, audio

I am trying to render an `html` snippet that contains the `<audio>` tag.

I have imported  `flutter_html`  and `flutter_html_audio`. I also have `chewie_audio` and `video_player` as dependencies.

Here is my code:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
   Map<int, LessonDO> lessonMap = ref.watch(lessonsProvider).lessonMap;
   LessonDO lesson = lessonMap[lessonNumber]!;
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
       leading: BackButton(
          onPressed: () => context.pop(),
       ),
       title: const Text("Menu"),
     ),
     body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Html(data: lesson.text!, customRenders: {
       audioMatcher(): audioRender(),
     })),
    );
 }
```

Throws exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError: init() has not been implemented.
#0      VideoPlayerPlatform.init
video_player_platform_interface.dart:43
#1      _videoPlayerPlatform
video_player.dart:28
#2      VideoPlayerController.initialize
video_player.dart:404
#3      ChewieAudioController._initialize
chewie_player.dart:130
<asynchronous suspension>
```

If I skip an exception in the debugger the page is rendered with audio control, but if control is tapped, the same exception is thrown again.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work.

The idea is to render `audio` tag as Icon, which when tapped calls some (any) audio player.

First, I downgraded `flutter_html` to 2.2.1. (stable version at the moment).

Second, removed `flutter_html_audio`, `chewie_player`, and `video_player` packages from dependencies.

Then, added `audioplayers` package instead.

Player:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class Player {
  static play(String src) async {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    await player.play(AssetSource(src));
  }
}
```

Render HTML:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Html(
    data: lesson.text!,
    customRender: {
      "audio": (context, child) {
        AudioContentElement audio = context.tree as AudioContentElement;
        String src = audio.src.first!;
        return IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.play_circle),
          tooltip: 'Воспроизвести',
          onPressed: () {
            Player.play(src);
          },
        );
      }
    },
  )),
```

My HTML snippet:

```
<h2>Some title</h2>
Some text<br>
<audio controls>
  <source src=\"audio/dictionary/audio_file.mp3\" 
          type=\"audio/mpeg\">
</audio><br><br>
 Some text
```

Assets specified as:

```
assets: 
- assets/audio/dictionary/
```